# How to authenticate user against salted and hashed password and username?

Tags: c#, encryption, hash

I am developing a .net web api project and need to store usernames and passwords salted and hashed in a users table.

How would I authenticate the user if the username and password fields are random hashed in the users table and the salts are stored in the same row for the user?  Am I missing something?  It seems as if I would have no way to find the user to do a password comparison.

Comment: Read this, please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Typically, the username can be stored in plain-text. Only the password needs to be salted/hashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not random hashed per se.  They are hashed against the same key.  As a result, to authenticate, you would need to repeat the hashing process for inputted credentials and compare that hash to the user's stored hash.

An additional option is to use the built in [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) providers to handle the authentication for you.

Your actual requirement of hashing both is actually a very difficult requirement to solve for.  As you identified, you would have nothing to identify that user by.  As a result, you would have to resort to using some sort data such as IP, user agent string, etc to make a best guess.  However, this would be incredibly dangerous.

At the end of the day, usernames are for identifying who the user is, not authenticating that user.  If you have security requirements to never display the username or otherwise protect the username, instead show them logged in with their first name or other identifier so that the username is not exposed.  At the end of the day you HAVE to find the user record and hashing the username only makes that harder and doesn't provide you any real security benefits.

Additional worthwhile security reading can be found [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1216/implementing-custom-authentication-for-aspnet)

Comment: I read several articles suggesting the use of salting to ensure randomness.  Are you saying that I should still be able to generate the same password that is stored in the database from what the user enters?

Comment: You cannot generate the same password.  This would be a security conflict of interest.  Rather, the user tries to login by entering their credentials. You fetch the hash and the salt from database for that username.
You use the salt to hash the plain text password that the user provided and finally, you compare the two hashes.  If they match, the user should be marked as authenticated.  The "randomness" is that the same salt is never used by two users.

Comment: What if I need to secure the username as well?  I could encrypt the username but it seems as if I would run into the same issue.  Is there a happy medium when you need to secure username and password?  Gotta love specs. :-)

Comment: You would have to repeat the same process.  The user would have a username salt.  The plain text username would be provided and you would hash it, comparing it against the username hash.  However, this seems like pretty extreme overkill.  Personally, I'd prefer that you issue an encrypted token for the user that represents them that is returned to the client, rather than hashing the username as well.  It seems a redundant, painful step for little benefit.  But, as you said, specs right? :P

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately.  Do you have any examples for the encrypted token scenario?  Also, if I were forced to encrypt the username and password, store the salt in the users table, how would I regenerate the hash if the salt is in the users table for the user I am looking for?  Thanks for being patient with me, this is quite a predicament.  SMH.

Comment: You can find quite a bit of information in a tutorial like http://tech.pro/tutorial/1216/implementing-custom-authentication-for-aspnet.  In addition, if you DID hash both password and username, you'd have to have separate salts for each, otherwise you wouldn't gain anything.  And since you have no internal identifier for a username (since it's hashed), you really don't have a way to lookup the user.  This becomes infinitely more problematic when you need to reset passwords.  My advice?  Leave the username as plain text and never display the username on the client and use their name to ID them

Comment: As David pointed out, hashing the username offers no benefits.  You could always hash all usernames with a common "Super Secret" salt, though, to appease those who don't know any better ;)

Comment: @PaulZaczkowski Fun trick :).  It's a great way to satisfy ridiculous requirements although at that point it is all just smoke and mirrors